# Trouble with string marshaling

Tags: c#, .net-core, pinvoke

I'm working on some code that calls into a native library for some computation. As you can see from the following code snippets I'm invoking a method that returns a `std::string`. My intention is to take that result convert it to a `char*` and marshal it back to my managed C# application. The catch here is, sometimes the `execution_result` will contain UTF-8 characters...

Code:

```cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall execute_payload(example::native_code* instance, char* payload, char** result) {
    std::string execution_result = instance->execute(payload);

    char* result_array = new char[execution_result.size() + 1];

    strcpy(result_array, execution_result.c_str());

    *result = result_array;

    return execution_result.length();
}
```

The following is a snippet of C# that yields expected results.

Code:

```cs
private HandleRef NativeInstance;

public Wrapper()
{
    NativeInstance = new HandleRef(this, NativeCode.CreateNew());
}

public string ExecuteNativeCode(string payload)
{
    IntPtr resultPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int));

    var resultLength = NativeCode.Execute(NativeInstance, payload, ref resultPointer);
    var resultBytes = new byte[resultLength - 1];

    Marshal.Copy(resultPointer, resultBytes, 0, resultLength - 1);

    var resultString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultBytes);

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(resultPointer);

    return resultString;
}
```

Expected Result:

```
123,45 €
```

Actual Result:

```
123,45 €
```

The following is an example of some code that I've tried in order to "simply" the marshaling of the string result. But it doesn't really work...

Code:

```cs
private HandleRef NativeInstance;

public Wrapper()
{
    NativeInstance = new HandleRef(this, NativeCode.CreateNew());
}

public string ExecuteNativeCode(string payload)
{
    IntPtr resultPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int));

    var resultLength = NativeCode.Execute(NativeInstance, payload, ref resultPointer);

    var resultString = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(resultPointer, resultLength);

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(resultPointer);

    return resultString;
}
```

Expected Result:

```
123,45 €
```

Actual Result:

```
㈱ⰳ㔴ꃂ苢¬缀\0ᴹ襴翻\0
```

I have two questions.

1. Why doesn't the second snippet work?
2. Regardless of why the second snippet doesn't work, what can I do better?

Thanks!

Comment: `Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int))` looks suspicious. It appears to be receiving a pointer (`*result = result_array;`) but you're only allocating 4 bytes. On a 64-bit architecture, you'd be overflowing the buffer. Perhaps you meant to allocate `IntPtr.Size`? Both allocate 4 bytes, so it's possible that the first implementation is masking the problem.

Comment: Also, memory leak... the result of `new char[execution_result.size() + 1]` is never freed.

Comment: We don't have the whole code, how you define C# is very important too. If you can adapt your C++ side, you could model it like some Windows API, for example: GetWindowText: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtextw then the proper interop is like this: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowtext

Comment: The question itself *may* be answered by this: the buffer is interpreted as UTF-8 in the first implementation but `Marshal.PtrToStringUni` interprets it as UTF-16 in the second.

Comment: Yep. The first character, `㈱`, is `\u3231`.  `0x31` and `0x32` are the values of `'1'` and `'2'`, respectively, in UTF-8, then `\u2c33`, from `'3'` and `','`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but considering you've already made a c++ helper function, why don't you just make a c++/CLI wrapper then simply return CLR types to your .NET code.  That's a simpler way and `eliminates any need for marshalling`

Comment: It looks like you took one byte data and encoded as unicode which packed the two bytes together as a single two byte character.  Then you started with a 8 characters that were one bytes, unicode expected two bytes to 8 garbage bytes were added to the array.

Comment: I've added the .net-core tag to make it clear the C++/CLI won't work.

I appreciate all the feedback! In all the "research" (aka Googling frantically) I haven't found a resource that lays out what needs to happen to make this work. Any additional guidance is appreciated.

Comment: If the first version works, stick with that, but also export a function that `delete`s that array you're allocating and call that before before `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(resultPointer);` to take care of that memory leak.